# Using convolution theorem to show that f*g = f(t-t_0) when g is a dirac delta function

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I'm still learning fourier and one of the questions I've been asked is related to convolution theorem. I am already struggling conceptually with this idea. We are told to consider a top-hat function g(t) centred on t=0 with width d. The second function h(t) is a dirac delta function centred on t_0, such that g(t) = (t-t_0). Using the convolution theorem, I am trying to show that f(t) * g(t) = f(t - t_0) where * denotes convolution. The question is asking me to do it without explicit calculation, but instead with definite statements (confused on that also).

Here is how I have attempted it:

Equation {1.1} is just the sifting property of the delta function
[image]

Comment: This might fit better at [math.se]. Also, for accessibility, please [type out mathematics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) rather than posting a photograph of text.